# How to iterate over a JSON object in JS and delete the specific JSON row based on condition

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I already searched, nothing matched so forget the copy pasted search before you ask rhetoric. :)

Anyway, in JavaScript(ES6), I have this JSON

```
var myJson = {
   'hello' : {x: 11, y:22},
   'there' : {x:99, y:100}
};
```

I know that to delete a JSON row, all I need is the **delete** keyword
But what I wanted to delete is based on the attribute condition, for example, I want to delete the row where X is greater than 50, which of course can be deleted by

```
delete myJson['there'].
```

But the problem is, I have no way of knowing in advance which key would meet the criteria so I cannot use delete. I have also searched and found(not sure if true?) that I cannot loop over this JSON and get the loop index so I can just splice the JSON row out, because this is not an array but an object.

Based on condition to exclude rows where X > 50, final intended output is:

```
myJson = {
       'hello' : {x: 11, y:22}
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just an object. JSON is the string version of the object created with `JSON.stringify(variableHere)`.

Comment: @vhutchison What is your point? This isn't an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The reason for the `hasOwnProperty` check is to ensure the key is an actual property of the object and doesn't come from the prototype.

```js
var myObject = {
   'hello' : {x: 11, y:22},
   'there' : {x:99, y:100}
};

for(var prop in myObject) {
    if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if(myObject[prop].x > 50) {
            delete myObject[prop];
        }
    }
}

console.log(myObject);
```

I renamed the variable to `myObject` because it wasn't JSON. To get the JSON from the object, you would do this following:

```js
var myObject = {
   'hello' : {x: 11, y:22},
   'there' : {x:99, y:100}
};

var myJson = JSON.stringify(myObject);

console.log(myJson);
```

Comment: @AdrianBorja Sure is! It's just a bit confusing if you're new to JS. Let me know if you have any other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJson = {
   'hello' : {x: 11, y:22},
   'there' : {x:99, y:100}
};


for( i in myJson) {
  if (myJson[i].x > 50) {
    delete myJson[i];
  }
}
```